# What's the right operation to calculate a percent when values differ?

Tags: percentages

Let say I assign a random amount of tasks to my employees and after a month, I want to check who is more **"productive"** based on the task they'd finished but, I think is not fair to give a 50% to someone who had finished 4 tasks of 8 assigned compared to someone who had finished 28 of 95 assigned tasks.

Something similar to this?

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
Employee &Assigned &Finished &Percent \\
\hline
Employee 1 &95 &28 &29.47 \\
\hline
Employee 2 &67 &22 &32.84 \\
\hline
Employee 3 &91 &37 &40.66 \\
\hline
Employee 4 &8 &4 &50.00 \\
\hline
Employee 5 &92 &51 &55.43 \\
\hline
Employee 6 &108 &63 &58.33 \\
\hline
Employee 7 &77 &47 &61.04 \\
\hline
Employee 8 &67 &44 &65.67 \\
\hline
Employee 9 &74 &54 &72.97 \\
\hline
Employee 10 &62 &48 &77.42 \\
\hline
\end{array}

What could be the correct operation to give a fair percent?

Comment: This is not a math question.

Comment: What site do you suggest to publish this question?

Comment: You clearly need to rate the tasks for expected time to complete.  Then you can just add up the expected time for all the completed tasks and compare that.  If you assign one person $100$ small tasks and another $8$ big tasks, is it possible the $8$ big tasks cannot be reasonably completed?  The whole premise of the question is flawed.

Comment: business related stack exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weighted average,  or with a bit of markup and margin possibly change percentages however you like. The problem is, we have nothing to weight with, except, amount of tasks completed with this information.

Comment: This helps, I realize I need to add more information to the data, like time for example.